# Differentiation and multiplication of polynomials can't be both continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

We define the two following linear maps:
$D:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x],\ D(p(x))=p'(x)$
$M:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x],\ M(p(x))=xp(x)$
I have to prove that for any norm $||.||$ on $\mathbb{R}[x]$, $D$ and $M$ can't be both continuous.
I have no clue on how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$MD(x^n)=nx^n$ for all $n$, therefore $$\sup_{p\in \Bbb R[x]\setminus \{0\}}\frac{\lVert MD(p)\rVert}{\lVert p\rVert}\ge \sup_{n\in\Bbb N} n=\infty$$

Since $M\circ D$ is not continuous, at least one of the two functions has not to be as well.